# Export CSV field formatting

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following script which identifies an account number based on the file name, and adds the list of accounts to a CSV file next to the date it was created.

```
$ReconFolder = "C:\Users\tenba1\Documents\QlikView\Account Recons"

Get-ChildItem $ReconFolder -Filter *.xls | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^Recon_\d{16,20}_\d+$'}  | ForEach-Object{ 

$id,$date = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[1..2]

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   "Account Number" = $id
   "Date Requested" = $date.Insert(4,'/').Insert(7,'/')
} 

} | sort-object DateCreated -Descending | Export-Csv $ReconFolder\itemList.CSV -    NoTypeInformation
```

There are 2 problems with it:

1. The sorting isn't working for some reason. I can get around this by re-importing the file, sorting, then exporting again, but would like to do it properly.
2. The Account Number can be between 16 and 20 digits - when sending this to `CSV` the format should be text. Currently an account number like this `10201314050019817277` ends up in the file like this: `10201314050019800000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting isn't working because the pipeline contains your PSObject which doesn't contain DateCreated, to include this add it to your object:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   "Account Number" = $id
   "Date Requested" = $date.Insert(4,'/').Insert(7,'/')
   "DateCreated"    = $_.CreationTime
}
```

With regards to the formatting of the number, check the csv in a text editor, I suspect that you are viewing the data in Excel and that the csv contains the correct data.